# 3T studio and node js giving deferent out put with same mongoDB query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have a mongoDB collection as below

```
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("60a245f4b828e75b584cdb12"),
    Name: "Ayaan Ansari",
    UserName: "anaan123@gmail.com",
    Mobile: "055",
    Addr1: "P . O . Box ",
    Addr2: "Ajman",
    Addr3: "",
    CompanyName: "Ayaan Technical Services LLC",
    Location: "Sharjah",
    TelNo: "055",
    mailID: "anaan123@gmail.com",
    status: "true",
    userRole: "customer",
    supplierList: [
      {
        supplierid: "60a0221697727e0108a25c0d",
        approved: false,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("60a2562b194fed38e86d01f4"),
    Name: "Amaan Ansari",
    UserName: "amaan123@gmail.com",
    Mobile: "055",
    Addr1: "P . O . Box",
    Addr2: "Ajman",
    Addr3: "",
    CompanyName: "Amaan Technical Services LLC",
    Location: "Umm Al Qwain",
    TelNo: "055",
    mailID: "amaan123@gmail.com",
    status: "true",
    userRole: "customer",
    supplierList: [
      {
        supplierid: "60a0221697727e0108a25c0d",
        approved: false,
      },
      {
        supplierid: "60953b6029b7082214db84e4",
        approved: false,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("60a295491086c054d83bf82e"),
    Name: "Shaji Kalangoth",
    UserName: "shaji@shaji.com",
    Mobile: "00",
    Addr1: "P . O . Box ",
    Addr2: "Ajman",
    Addr3: "",
    CompanyName: "Shaji IT Services LLC",
    Location: "Abu Dhabi",
    TelNo: "00",
    mailID: "00",
    status: "true",
    userRole: "customer",
  },
]
```

When I use below query in 3T Studio I am getting correct result what I need

```
db.getCollection("user").find(
  {
    userRole: "customer",
  },
  {
    supplierList: {
      $elemMatch: {
        supplierid: "60953b6029b7082214db84e4",
        approved: false,
      },
    },

    Name: 1,
    UserName: 1,
    Mobile: 1,
    CompanyName: 1,
    Location: 1,
    userRole: 1,
  },
);
```

Resullt :-

```
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("60a245f4b828e75b584cdb12"),
    Name: "Ayaan Ansari",
    UserName: "anaan123@gmail.com",
    Mobile: "055",
    CompanyName: "Ayaan Technical Services LLC",
    Location: "Sharjah",
    userRole: "customer",
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("60a2562b194fed38e86d01f4"),
    Name: "Amaan Ansari",
    UserName: "amaan123@gmail.com",
    Mobile: "055",
    CompanyName: "Amaan Technical Services LLC",
    Location: "Umm Al Qwain",
    userRole: "customer",
    supplierList: [
      {
        supplierid: "60953b6029b7082214db84e4",
        approved: false,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("60a295491086c054d83bf82e"),
    Name: "Shaji Kalangoth",
    UserName: "shaji@shaji.com",
    Mobile: "00",
    CompanyName: "Shaji IT Services LLC",
    Location: "Abu Dhabi",
    userRole: "customer",
  },
]
```

but when i use in node js the second document shows all objects but i need to show only one object which fulfilling the criteria. in 3T Studio the code working fine and getting only the required array object.

```
let allCustomers = await db
  .get()
  .collection(collection.USER_COLLECTION)
  .find(
    {
      userRole: "customer",
    },
    {
      supplierList: {
        $elemMatch: {
          supplierid: "60953b6029b7082214db84e4",
          approved: false,
        },
      },
      Name: 1,
      UserName: 1,
      Mobile: 1,
      CompanyName: 1,
      Location: 1,
      userRole: 1,
    },
  )
  .toArray();
```

The result : -

```
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("60a245f4b828e75b584cdb12"),
    Name: "Ayaan Ansari",
    UserName: "anaan123@gmail.com",
    Mobile: "055",
    CompanyName: "Ayaan Technical Services LLC",
    Location: "Sharjah",
    userRole: "customer",
    supplierList: [
      {
        supplierid: "60a0221697727e0108a25c0d",
        approved: false,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("60a2562b194fed38e86d01f4"),
    Name: "Amaan Ansari",
    UserName: "amaan123@gmail.com",
    Mobile: "055",
    CompanyName: "Amaan Technical Services LLC",
    Location: "Umm Al Qwain",
    userRole: "customer",
    supplierList: [
      {
        supplierid: "60a0221697727e0108a25c0d",
        approved: false,
      },
      {
        supplierid: "60953b6029b7082214db84e4",
        approved: false,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("60a295491086c054d83bf82e"),
    Name: "Shaji Kalangoth",
    UserName: "shaji@shaji.com",
    Mobile: "00",
    CompanyName: "Shaji IT Services LLC",
    Location: "Abu Dhabi",
    userRole: "customer",
  },
]
```

I don't know why this result is deferent please someone help me to solve this please .....

Answer (score 1):

> In Node

Query:-

```
let allCustomers = await db.get().collection("user").find({ userRole: "customer" })
.project({
supplierList: {
$elemMatch: {
supplierid: "60953b6029b7082214db84e4",
approved: false,
},
},
Name: 1,
UserName: 1,
Mobile: 1,
CompanyName: 1,
Location: 1,
userRole: 1,
})
.toArray();
```

Result: -

```
[
  {
    _id: 60a3e64e8237c52d04dbde9a,
    Name: 'Ayaan Ansari',
    UserName: 'anaan123@gmail.com',
    Mobile: '055',
    CompanyName: 'Ayaan Technical Services LLC',
    Location: 'Sharjah',
    userRole: 'customer'
  },
  {
    _id: 60a3e64e8237c52d04dbde9b,
    Name: 'Amaan Ansari',
    UserName: 'amaan123@gmail.com',
    Mobile: '055',
    CompanyName: 'Amaan Technical Services LLC',
    Location: 'Umm Al Qwain',
    userRole: 'customer',
    supplierList: [ [Object] ]
  },
  {
    _id: 60a3e64e8237c52d04dbde9c,
    Name: 'Shaji Kalangoth',
    UserName: 'shaji@shaji.com',
    Mobile: '00',
    CompanyName: 'Shaji IT Services LLC',
    Location: 'Abu Dhabi',
    userRole: 'customer'
  }
]
```

Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

```
let allCustomers = await db.get().collection("user").find({ userRole: "customer" })
.project({
supplierList: {
$elemMatch: {
supplierid: "60953b6029b7082214db84e4",
approved: false,
},
},
 Name: 1,
 UserName: 1,
 Mobile: 1,
 CompanyName: 1,
 Location: 1,
 userRole: 1,
 })
 .toArray();
```

Thank you .....